# android: unable to open pdf file from html link in android

Tags: android

**[PDF - BOOK](/mnt/sdcard/giraffe/physics/p-chapter1.pdf)**

The above html file i am calling it in android web view from assets. And the page is displayed but link to pdf is not working ?

Comment: When you say not working, I assume you mean it's a dead link? Could you paste some code to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");
```

you should add this url: `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=` before your url